# Microsoft Bot Framework exit dialog and dispose of parents

Tags: c#, botframework

I have 4 dialogs, each spawns as a child if a certain condition is met.
When I test locally, everything works fine, but when I publish to azure, it doesn't. 
I get a generic error:

> Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.

I believe I have identified where the issue lies, so I want to post the message to the client and then exit everything.
I have this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets our products
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task<List<ProductResponseModel>> GetCurrentProducts(IDialogContext context)
{

    try
    {

        // If we don't have any products, get them
        if (_products == null)
            _products = await _productProvider.ListAsync();

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {

        // Throw our error
        await context.PostAsync(ex.Message);

        // Exit our dialog
        await ResumeAfter(context, null);
    }

    // Return our filtered products
    return _products;
}

/// <summary>
/// When the child dialog has completed, mark this as done
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current context</param>
/// <param name="result">The result object</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result) => context.Done<IMessageActivity>(null);
```

If there is an error, it should post the error message to the user, then it invokes **ResumeAfter** which invokes `context.Done`. I believe that should end the current dialog and all others. Is this right? Or is there another way I should be doing it. All my dialogs implement `IDialog<object>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe the return of the products should be inside of your try block.

`context.Done` will just end the current dialog, not all the dialogs in the stack. In fact, the `context.Done` will trigger the `ResumeAfter<T>` method that you define when you called this current dialog (meaning in your parent dialog).

Alternatively, you can also use `context.Fail` if you want to return an exception, in that case, you will have to handle the exception in the `ResumeAfter<T>` method of the parent.

You can read more about this in the [Multi-Dialogs sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs).

Comment: I can't have the return of the products in the try catch block, because it moans that not all code paths return a result (even when using context.Fail). Other than that, everything else you suggested was great.